# postresql join tables without checking where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to run a PostgreSQL query to calculate the usage of the bed. This returns the correct result

```
SELECT (COUNT(id)/3293::float)*100 AS Bed_Utilization 
FROM public.patient_visits 
WHERE dischargedate IS NULL;
```

When I join the two tables like running the query below

```
SELECT (COUNT(pv.id)/SUM(numofbeds)::float)*100 As Bed_Utilization
FROM public.patient_location pl 
JOIN public.patient_visits pv
ON pl.id = pv.assignedpatientlocation
WHERE pv.dischargedate IS NULL;
```

It is not returning the result I wanted. I believe it repeats adding the numofbeds based on the where condition. When I run the query below

```
SELECT SUM(pl.numofbeds) 
FROM public.patient_location pl
JOIN public.patient_visits pv
ON pl.id = pv.assignedpatientlocation
WHERE pv.dischargedate IS NULL;
```

It returns the result of 47209. However, I want to calculate the sum of the numofbeds (which should be 3293) by just adding the number in the patient_location table.

Is that any way to do that in join tables? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want ?

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(pv.id)
    FROM public.patient_location pl 
    JOIN public.patient_visits pv
       ON pl.id = pv.assignedpatientlocation
    WHERE pv.dischargedate IS NULL) 
    / 
    (SELECT SUM(numofbeds)::float
     FROM public.patient_location pl)
    * 100 AS Bed_Utilization;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want a `JOIN` to get the numerator:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM public.patient_visits pv
        WHERE pv.dischargedate IS NULL
       ) * 100.0 /
       (SELECT SUM(numofbeds)
        FROM public.patient_location pl
       ) AS Bed_Utilization;
```